# 'No such module' even though listed in dependencies?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm working with Swift 5 and Xcode 14.3. I have a project that I had working previously, but as of last night I am getting an error "No such module 'SQLite'" even though I have added the packaged to the dependencies array in Package.swift.  Again, it was working perfectly last week, and now has decided otherwise.  I tried cleaning the build folder with no results, and I tried to reset the package cache, but all the options under Packages-> are greyed out, like Xcode doesn't know there's any package at all.  This is the only dependency in my project, so it can't be an interference error.

My Package.swift:

```
// swift-tools-version: 5.7

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "AsyncMux",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v15), .macOS(.v12)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "AsyncMux",
            targets: ["AsyncMux"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git", from: "0.14.1")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "AsyncMux",
            dependencies: [
                .package(url: "https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git", from: "0.14.1")
            ],
            path: "Sources"
        ),
    ]
)
```